# Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates a context file with error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Got the following Database:

```
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Emp]    Script Date: 2/25/2013 09:52:26 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Age] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Emp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

When i try to do Entity Framework -> reverse engineer code first on an empty project in Visual Studio 2012 c# i get the following error in the DBContext as soon as it is done

Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database.get'

why might that be?
[image]

EDIT:

Worked in an empty project
doesn't work on a non empty project

Comment: Have you installed the Entity Framework NuGet package?

Comment: @qujck yes did "Install-Package EntityFramework"
reply => 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already installed.

Comment: You are trying to make a static constructor to non-static class. This wont works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Database" is a commonly used class/namespace/variable name, so it's getting confused as to which one you mean. Notice that the error mentioned "System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database". Just qualify it with "System.Data.Entity" to get the correct one:

System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(null);